# JQuery UI datepicker localization

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm trying to get a Hebrew Calendar on JQueryUI Datepicker.
For some reason, it always stays in English.

This is my code:

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional[ "" ] );
$( ".calendar_date" ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "he" ] );
```

Thanks!

Comment: did u include   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui/i18n/ui.datepicker-he.js"></script>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you downloaded and included in your page the localized calendar? 
You can find it and download it from [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/localization.html) - check the source of the page, the Hebrew Calendar is [this](http://jqueryui.com/ui/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-he.js). 
You should download and include this js in your page.

Comment: Right now it is included in the bundle. Download the full ui zip from http://jqueryui.com/download/ and you will find it inside development-bundle/ui/i18n directory

Comment: Above Given Links Are Not Working Please Fix, Need Help on Hebrew Calander, Thank You.