# How to get both JQuery-UI and datepicker localizations using NPM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, datepicker

I am building a wonderful web application with Laravel, defining my javascript dependencies with the `package.json`, and all is going well. 
Until when I need to use a JQuery datepicker with a default italian localization.

Looking in SO, I get a million of suggestions about JQuery-UI and localization, like [JQuery UI datepicker localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888452/jquery-ui-datepicker-localization),  [Localization not working in jQuery UI datePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28452270/localization-not-working-in-jquery-ui-datepicker) and [jQuery UI Datepicker localization error on load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15254497/jquery-ui-datepicker-localization-error-on-load) . Sadly, nothing about how to make it work with NPM and moreover with a localization file needed.

I could download the source files and use them, but I managed to be tidy until now, and I'd love to find out how to use NPM for my datepicker too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a ton of attempts, here is a working version.

First of all, define all of the dependencies in `package.json`

```
...
"jquery-ui-dist": "^1.12.1",
"jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
...
```

Notice that I need **BOTH** the `jquery-ui-dist` version (for the minimized version that we will use) and the `jquery-ui`, for the localization file.

That said, I have to copy my files from the `node_modules` folder (that I don't export in production) to the `public/js` folder, and I do it adding these rows in `webpack.mix.js`

```
...
.scripts('node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.min.js','public/js/jquery-ui.min.js')
.scripts('node_modules/jquery-ui/ui/i18n/datepicker-it.js','public/js/datepicker-it.js')
...
```

Last but not least, I add the import of the javascript files in my page,

```
<script src="/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/datepicker-it.js"></script>
```

and this makes the trick, loading the datepicker in italian language by default